# Apache SOLR show only nodes with images

Tags: 7, search

How can I filter SOLR results to show only nodes with images? There seems to be no support for image fields. I don't mind writing custom field mapping or something like that but some guidelines would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the template file that outputs your SOLR items with a check for a set image field.

This type of check is generally ok to use in a template file:

```
<?php if(isset($item['image'])): ?>
  <?php print render($item); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not an option. I need a filter that users can select, just the same way as they select content type or taxonomy terms via facets.

Answer (score 0):

What if you:

- Create an exposed filter for the image field
- In the configuration select `Filter type to expose: Grouped Filters`
- Set `Widget type: Select`
- At the bottom:

  - create a label `Having image`, `Operator: Is not empty`
  - create second label `Not having image` `Operator: Is empty`

Save and check

Comment: I'm not using views for that. Only SOLR and Faced API.